# Calculating surface area of part of a sphere

Tags: geometry

Consider the Earth to be a sphere with radius $6400 \mathrm{km}$.  How do I calculate the surface area of the sphere between 30°S and 30°N (or any other pair of latitudes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find the area of the spherical caps on either side, and subtract it from the total surface area $4\pi r^2$

For the area of the spherical caps, you can use

$A = \Omega r^2$

where the angle $\Omega$ is the solid angle(steradians) of a cone whose cross-section subtends the angle θ at the center, given by

$\Omega = 2\pi (1 - cos\theta) $

Answer (score 0):

$$ \text {Area of a spherical cap (A) = } 2 \pi r^2 .(1 - cos \theta) $$
$$ \text {where } \theta \text { is the angle between the apex of the cap and base of the cap}$$
$$ \text {So, at } 30^0N \text { and } 30^0S \text {,  } \theta = 60^0$$
$$ \text {Area of the spherical cap at } 30^0N =  2 \pi r^2 .(1 - cos 60^0) = \pi r^2$$
$$ \text {Area of the spherical cap at } 30^0S =  2 \pi r^2 .(1 - cos 60^0) = \pi r^2$$
$$ \text {Area of the surface between } 30^0N \text { and } 30^0S = 4 \pi r^2 - \pi r^2 - \pi r^2 = 2 \pi r^2 \text { or } \frac {1} {2}.S $$
$$\text {Where S = Surface area of the earth}$$